# What does "I'm a while." mean?

Tags: meaning

Would someone tell me what does the meaning of second sentence:

> Text me when you have time.
>   Will do, **I am a while**.

Thank you.

Comment: I think it is: "Will do, ***in a while***." : http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/in+a+while

Comment: Where did you find the sentence? Did you hear it or read it? Do you have a link to the original?

Comment: It makes no sense at all to me. I think Isaac Pounder is correct.#

Comment: The question may well be removed as just an example of a typo (and hence not a question suitable for ELU) unless you provide at least some background.

Answer (score 3):

(I would post in a comment but rep is too small).
This looks like an "auto-correct" from In a while (someone typed "Im" a while and it switched it to I am a while).

Im is a frequent typo for I'm (versus in)

Comment: ......Brilliant.